# How to press browser shortcuts keys with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use browsers shortcut with pyhton selenium but I can't get any shortcut to work.

For example, I am trying to open a new tab ( Control + T ) using `ActionChains()`. I tried the following two but nothing seems to change:

```
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('T').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

and

```
element = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
element.click()
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('T').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

What is the proper way to use shortcuts in python selenium?

Answer (score 0):

Browser shortcuts seem to be unreliable with Selenium. I would open a new tab with javascript:

```
driver.execute_script("window.open()")
```

Comment: I trying to find a way to use shortcuts in general. Like F9,Control+Tab etc.
Is there a way to find the corresponding script for every one of them?

Comment: The thing is, switching tabs does not actually do anything in selenium. It changes the visual viewport sure, but your driver is still aimed at the initial tab.

Comment: Very good to know! However, not even the shortcut for reloading the page does work. So is there a way to find the javascript for every one of them? Or what could be wrong with my script and doesn't do what is being told?

Comment: I would suggest having a thorough read of the selenium documentation. You can refresh the page by using ```driver.refresh()```